# Limiting Parallel Connections with iptables in Centos

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

Currently using Centos6.7 and looking to put some limits in place to stop say user x from ip y from making more than say 5 connections. Say he logs in 5 times, those 5 will establish but the 6th will be rejected.

Looking in to using connlimit to do this but feel like I'm missing something and I'm slightly gun shy around putting the rule in place as I've inadvertently locked myself out of the server in the past putting a rule in the wrong spot (oops).

Notes: Not looking to specify a port. x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.2 are IP's with higher limits of 50 so I put those rules first, I believe that's correct?

I have the below:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -s x.x.x.1 --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -p tcp -s x.x.x.2 --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT
```

Does this look correct? Is there a different way to go about this? I don't want to limit to a pool of only 5 connections total but 5 per IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Almost, but not quite there. The rules you created would first reject connections above 50 from `x.1` and `x.2`, and then reject any connections above 5 from anywhere, *including* `x.1` and `x.2`. You need to have an `ACCEPT` rule for those two sources before the common limiter.

It may be easiest to invert the match on the `connlimit`:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -s x.x.x.1 --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-upto 50 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -s x.x.x.2 --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-upto 50 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-upto 5 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j REJECT
```

You might want to put those rules in a chain of their own so you don't need to repeat the common parts (`-p tcp --syn`), and with a separate chain you can also replace `ACCEPT` with `RETURN` if you want to do other filtering after those rules. The accepting rule would need to appear somewhere else, then.

The default for `connlimit` is to work per source address, so it should be what you want. Though note that `iptables` doesn't have any concept of "logging in", so if you actually want to limit logins on an application level, you'll need to do it there.

---

To prevent yourself from getting locked out, you might want to make sure you have a separate rule very first to allow administrative access from your machine (SSH perhaps, at least already established connections). Another possibility would be to use `cron` or `at` to reset the firewall rules to some known-good configuration after a moment, so even if you do get locked out, it won't last. You'll just have to remember to remove that safeguard when you're done.

Comment: That makes sense for sure.  I went ahead and threw a rule in early to allow my address (and a separate VPN as a backup) ssh access.  I had originally limited to 5, had myself locked out, and needed to wait on active connections to drop below 5 to log back in -_-.  So I should just look at it kinda backwards as you suggested, my x.1 and x.2 addresses should accept up to 50, accept up to 5 for everything else, then a flat reject to cover the remaining? (assuming I'm reading that correct).

Comment: @Hollyw00d, yeah, that would seem simplest in this case. In any case you need to somehow make the connections from `x.1` and `x.2` go around the  common rule. An `ACCEPT` or `RETURN` before it seems easiest, since `iptables` doesn't have an "if ... else if ... else ..." construct.

Comment: @ikkachu Much appreciated, thanks for the help!